# ivona tts and how to get programmatically list of all installed voices?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts and all their voices. How can i programmatically get list of all installed voices from ivona tts?

Is there any command for this in android SDK 8?

Can i programmatically change pico tts for ivona tts? Not for whole phone just for my program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get list of installed TTS engines you should get uid of *com.ivona.tts* package:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int%29
and then ask **PackageManager** for all applications that share this uid:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackagesForUid(int%29

To change TTS engine use this method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setEngineByPackageName(java.lang.String%29

(Please note, that this method is deprecated and on newer API levels you should use the following constructor:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#TextToSpeech(android.content.Context,%20android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener,%20java.lang.String%29)

Finally to set specific Ivona voice you must parse language/country/name from voice package name and pass it to:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setLanguage(java.util.Locale%29
eg. to choose com.ivona.tts.voicebeta.eng.gbr.amy you should use:

```
tts.setLanguage(new Locale("eng", "gbr", "amy"));
```

Here's sample Activity that prints available voices to logcat:

```
package com.example.com.ivona.tts.test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

public class TTSActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private static final String TAG = "TTSActivity";
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(TTSActivity.this, TTSActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

        ApplicationInfo ai = null;
        try {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.ivona.tts", 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        String[] ivonaVoices = pm.getPackagesForUid(ai.uid);

        Log.d(TAG, "Possible tts.setLanguage() usage:");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^com\\.ivona\\.tts\\.voicebeta\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)$");
        for (String voice: ivonaVoices) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(voice);
            if (m.matches())
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("tts.setLanguage(\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\")", m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and another example if anyone need for getting all installed packages: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/03/how-to-get-information-about-all-the-applications-installed-in-your-android-emulator-or-phone-how-to-use-getpackagemanager-in-android/

Comment: But in this case we don't want all installed packages, only those that have common sharedUid with com.ivona.tts.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a simpler way would be to use the following code from any activity class:

```
final int TTS_CHECK_DATA = 977; // arbitrary number
private ArrayList<String> myVoices = null;
```

In some activity class method:

```
Intent in = new Intent(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
// if you want specific, non-default TTS Engine also set package, else skip:
in = in.setPackage("com.acapelagroup.android.tts"); // or whatever package you want
startActivityForResult(in, TTS_CHECK_DATA);
```

Then in onActivityResult():

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TTS_CHECK_DATA && data != null) {
        myVoices = data.getStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES);
    }
}
```

Now myVoices is filled with locale strings (lang-country-variant), e.g. for Acapela I get:

```
pol-POL-Ania
eng-USA-Heather
eng-GBR-Rachel
rus-RUS-Alyona
```

TTS Engines that have only one speaker per voice may not give you the 3rd (variant) component, e.g. Ivona for now gives you only "eng-USA", "eng-GBR", "fra-FRA" etc.

Greg